# How to detect if object is a certain height after page load?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to, after a page has loaded (maybe 2 seconds), check if the page displays a given object at a certain height or not, then upon that condition display a different object (if the first given object is not displayed at the height I want it to be displayed at), or do nothing extra (if object is at least the height I want).

Comment: Simple search will get you there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Comment: That doesn't really explain how to make a condition of whether something is displaying (or displaying in a certain way) and then if it isn't then add something else

Comment: Hey Justin not trying to be mean, but each one of your problems can be broken down into easy searches. You can pretty much copy and paste what you find:  https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+check+height+of+div&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS698US698&oq=jquery+check+height&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.9151j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8       https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+if+else&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS698US698&oq=jquery+if+else&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4271j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The reason why no one has answered this yet is that generally questions that are asked here should have some sort of work already attempted. If you search for Jquery solutions or Javascript try on something like jsfiddle, fail, then update the question with your attempt I would be happy to help you get the rest of the way.